# "Today" Score off by 2 due to rep cap and un-downvote afterwards

Tags: bug, reputation, downvotes, daily-reputation-limit

I have gotten a curious situation where I have earned more reputation than for "max.20 upvotes + 4 accepts":

[image]

The entire sum of the reputation checks out, it actually sums up to 262.
stackoverflow.com/reputation however says I "only" gained 260 reputation:

> -- 2015-12-27 rep +258  = 10429
>    2  34485893 (10)
>    2  34485701 (10)
>    2  34485893 (10)
>    2  34485454 (10)
>    2  34485454 (10)
>    1  34492337 (15)
>    2  34492582 (10)
>    2  34492582 (10)
>    2  34492582 (10)
>    1  34480837 (15)
>    2  34493301 (10)
>    2  34493301 (10)
>    2  34493301 (10)
>    2  34496272 (10)
>    1  34496774 (15)
>    2  34496774 (10)
>    2  34496991 (10)
>    2  34496991 (10)
>    2  34496991 (10)
>    2  34496991 (10)
>    2  34496991 (10)
>    2  34496991 (10)
>    1  34496991 (15)
>    2  34497161 [10]
>    3  34496272 [-2]
>    2  34497161 [2]
>    2  34493301 [0]
>    2  34496991 [0]
>   -- 2015-12-28 rep +260  = 10689

Unfortunately there were a few up and downs during the day - I have got one downvote which was later removed and one more downvote which still exists.
I have gotten more than 20 upvotes total and got accepted exactly 4 times.

I have gotten the downvotes while not having hit the rep cap yet. After surpassing the rep cap one of the downvotes got removed. I would assume that the removed downvote (`+2`) caused the display to be a little confused.

- Is that enough information?
- Is that a somewhat known bug? Or a extreme corner case?
- What will be my actual reputation at the end of the day? 260? 262?

Comment: @Makoto only positive changes? Yesterday I got negative ones tracked as well: http://i.imgur.com/wFjuV6f.png

Comment: No, sorry, that was just patently wrong.  I'll muse a bit more about this when I have more time to think about what may be going on. :/